# Restore oracle database on a new machine with only datafiles and control files?

Tags: oracle, restore, oracle-11g-r2

I lost my laptop and I had an oracle database 11g r2 in it but I still have all the data files, create control files script and nothing else now I bought new laptop and I want to get my data back with only data files ? Is it possible and If so how? **The operating system in my old laptop (server) was windows server 2012.**

Please help me I have important data and I need to restore it. I’ve copied the latest datafiles, and also I have the create control file script of my old sercer . Is there anything I can do and If so , please explain it to me in detail. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you followed the documentation for user-managed recovery with missing control files: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/backup.1111/e10642/osrecvry.htm#i1011065